# Create a 'single-serving site' with python

Tags: python, web-services, web-frameworks

I want to make a Python script available as a service on the net. The script, which is my first 'proper' Python program, takes a txt file as argument and writes an image into the work directory. So:

- How difficult is it for somebody who is new to Python and web development?
- How much work is it?
- Do I need a framework (Django, cherryPy, web2py)?
- Are there good tutorials?
- How do I avoid the server to be compromised?
- What are my next steps?

  **==> What is the easiest way?**

In the end it is enough, if it is a white page, with some text, and a button, which when clicked, opens a file dialog. After the txt is processed, the server should just return the image, which was written on the hard drive. Already I have access to a server which has Ubuntu installed through a friend.

**[update]**

Thanks for all your answers. After reading them I want to stress again, that I want to have it as minimal as possible. Srikar's suggestion sounds like the easiest one:

> Put it in executable directory of your OS (commonly known as CGI
>   path). Provide a simple HTML form & upon form submission hit this
>   script which executes & returns back the image you want to display.

Any objections or comments? Do you know any tutorials for that?

**[udpate2]**

I found this SO answer: [File Sharing Site in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900514/file-sharing-site-in-python/2900646#2900646) Is this a sensible approach?

Comment: That's many, many questions rolled into one there, and no doubt many answers!

Comment: Hi Raz, thank you for your feedback. I see the same problem, but I am under the impression, that all questions have the same core and that you can't answer one without touching another one. I tried to summarize them with: 'What is the easiest way?'

Comment: If all you need is CGI, it's all very quick and easy. The hard part would be to create an image, but since you are not asking about that, I guess you have some idea how to accomplish that already. Google for CGI python tutorials, you should be fine with reading only one, in an hour or less.

Comment: using CGI as the server gateway is certainly easy, but I'd still advise against following the CGI python tutorials; python's `cgi` module is unpleasant.  Fortunately, you can easily wrap the more modern [wsgi](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) with a [cgi handler](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler) and get the best of both worlds (easy deployment, useful python web framework knowledge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created what I needed with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/).

They have a well documented pattern / tutorial on [Uploading Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/). The tutorial is understandable even for people with little python and web expericence.

To get a first working version it took me 2h and the resulting code was only 50 lines. This includes, starting the webserver, having a html file/form with file upload and serving a file back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not too difficult. Actually, it sounds like a good first project.
2. That too subjective to answer. An hour to days.
3. No, you don't need one, but I'd use one if I were you. They abstract away some of the stuff you really don't care about, and you'll learn a tool you can use again in the future.
4. Plenty. If you want a real rundown of how Python works for the web, read the [HOWTO from Python.org](http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html). If you just want to learn how to do this one project, pick a framework and do their tutorial.
5. This question is so broad and complex that I'm not going to try to answer it. Search this site, or Google, for questions like that.
6. Your next step should be to pick a framework; I've used [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) successfully. Just download it, follow the installation instructions, and work your way through their tutorial; it should tell you everything you need to know to do what you want. If you still have questions once you've learned how to do the basics, come back and ask again!

Edit: The answer to that other question will certainly work for you. There, they just receive a GET request and respond with data from a Python file. You need to receive a GET request, respond with an HTML page (easy enough), then respond to a POST request that includes an uploaded file (slightly more complicated) and run your python routine on the uploaded file and then respond with the created image (or a link to it).

Take a look at [this page](http://jeremiahgoyette.com/simple-python-server/) which includes a simple Python script to do file uploads. You should easily be able to modify it to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

- How difficult is it for somebody who is new to Python and web development?

  Depends on your level of knowledge.
- How much work is it?

  Depends on which method you choose to solve the problem.
- Do I need a framework (Django, cherryPy, web2py)?

  Not necessarily - you could get started by using the CGI (http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html)
- Are there good tutorials?

  Yes, there are plenty. The Python docs are an excellent place to start.
- How do I avoid the server to be compromised?

  Again, depends on the method you choose to solve the problem, although there are commonalities.
- What are my next steps?

  Dare I say it again, choose a method, read the docs, have a play!

Answer (score 0):

If its just as simple as you have described it. Then you might not even need Django. You could simply use `CGI` scripting. All of these design decisions, depend on whether

1. You need (or foresee) a SQL storage?
2. or a Content-Management-System?
3. Will you need multiple-user support?
4. Do you need tight security?
5. Do you need different privileges for different users?
6. Do you need an `Admin` to manage your site?

If the answer to above questions is atleast 60% correct, then you might consider Django. otherwise, just write a python script. Put it in executable directory of your OS (commonly known as CGI path). Provide a simple HTML form & upon form submission hit this script which executes & returns back the image you want to display. So, it all depends on the features you need...

Comment: Hi Srikar, I need none of the features. You don't know by any chance a tutorial just covering: "Put it in executable directory of your OS (commonly known as CGI path). Provide a simple HTML form & upon form submission hit this script which executes & returns back the image you want to display"

Comment: try this - http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/feature_5min_python.html or http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/cgi/