# Django: let user download a large file

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, django-views

I am building a private file upload site. Alice uploads a file, Bob downloads it.

People other than Alice and Bob should not have access. I was first thinking about giving the file a complex name ( `http://domain/download/md5sum.zip`), but I want an expiring link. So something like `http://domain/download/tempkey/aaa123/file.zip`. This will give me more control over file downloading and logging.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900646 . It suggests the following:

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        # The URL the client requested
        print self.path

        # analyze self.path, map the local file location...

        # open the file, load the data
        with open('test.py') as f: data = f.read()

        # send the headers
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream') # you may change the content type
        self.end_headers()
        # If the file is not found, send error code 404 instead of 200 and display a message accordingly, as you wish.

        # wfile is a file-like object. writing data to it will send it to the client
        self.wfile.write(data)
```

But how do I get this to work in Django? A views function should return a HTTPResponse object, which this doesn't do.

Comment: Do not use django for file download handing, use Apache x-sendfile instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Django to download large files isn't really recommended. Usually you'd have a front-end multiplexer such as NginX, and use Django only to validate the file.

Then, if the download is validated, you'd issue a signal to the multiplexer. For NginX, you can set up a special header ("X-Accel-Redirect") to point to the true location of the local file. Django will only serve a few bytes, and all the heavy lifting will be taken up by NginX; at the same time the original URL will be that of Django, so that it is not possible to bypass security.

See: http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel

You can find notes on how to serve static files (extensible with authentication) here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

but as the page says, it is "*a quick and dirty helper view*" not intended for production or high-traffic sites. That's not what Django was designed to do, even if it *can* do it.