# Sending 1gb data as a response to POST request

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am running a django web app where I have one form which accepts text area input. I am sending that text to my view by POST request. After processing that input at server my generated output is of 1GB. Now the question is how can I send that data back to browser. I want that whole data at client side. How can I do it.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want the webserver to do much heavy work. The ideal way would be to  generate the output to a file, upload this file to a django storage and return the file path to the client. You might want to consider doing calculations and generation of the output on a different server as well.

Take a look at these links

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also here is a related question:

[Django: let user download a large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408414/django-let-user-download-a-large-file)